# What should the title of this Harry Potter question be?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Since people can't keep their grubby little paws off other people's questions, we now have to have the community decide on how to name this question properly: [Why did this character name his son after Snape?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109234/29220)

It was initially

> Why did Harry Potter name his son after Snape?

but a few users said it was spoilerish so a mod stepped in and removed the spoilers from the title, and then 24634 other users thought they would contribute and override the mod's decision.

Comment: Related discussions to consider: [Is it okay to have spoilers in question titles?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/835/5184) and [Character Death Spoilers In Title](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6855/5184)

Comment: dont forget, that the fact that harrypoter has kids, is plot/title of JKR's play. so her own works are spoiling previous works in that reguard.

Comment: is the harsh tone in the first sentence really necessary, given that editing other people's questions is *explicitly encourage* on Stack sites.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield i drip passive aggressive >:)

Comment: @Himarm Not in the *title* of her play. And later works spoiling earlier works is kinda par for the course! :-)

Comment: I vote for "Book series with magic boy and mean teacher"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the current title of,

> Why did this character name his s̶e̶c̶o̶n̶d̶ son after Snape?

is a perfect spoiler free title, that fits my, the questions author, intent.

This is also essentially what Pureferret originally changed it to, to edit out spoilers.

Comment: Who are you, the author, to make sure a decision?

Comment: @JackBNimble i know right?!?!

Comment: Hm, interesting. Before seeing the age of the question and the notice by Keen under it, I was just about to edit the spoiler out of the title, although I did rather think the obvious spoiler-free option (“Why did this character name his son after this character?”) sounded a bit hedgy. Definitely wouldn’t call the current version spoiler-free, though.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion was:

> Why did Harry honor Snape this way?

---

As an aside, it'd be easy to rewrite the question to have the appropriate spoiler tag, without hiding the whole question:

"Pertaining to the events in the Epilogue of the series, also seen at the end of the last film, why would Harry

> name one of his sons Albus *Severus* Potter?

After all those years of distrusting, and being bullied by Snape, does Harry every give a reason for doing this, or has JKR ever expanded on why?"

Comment: -1: this is a big spoiler for anyone who doesn't know the Big Reveal about Snape in DH.

Comment: @randal'thor How? The title *makes no reference to any part of the series or any point in the timeline*. It could be talking about him paying respect in a class at any point in the series after Harry meets Snape. You only think it's a spoiler because you've read it and can back-fill the info. Without that, it's completely generic.

Comment: But "honouring" a man he dislikes is different from paying respect in a class. Respect is expected from student to teacher, even though in Snape's case Harry is reluctant to show such respect throughout the series ("you don't have to call me 'sir', Professor").

Comment: @rand Honor is generic. You're applying assumptions based on what you already know.

Answer (score -2):

I might also suggest

> Why is this character named after Snape?

as this makes it less obvious that it is someone's child.

Comment: Well, "named after" does imply, to me at least, that they are someone's child who knew Snape.

Comment: Yes, but it just feels to me like it makes it more ambiguous of whether or not it was a main character or not. Not sure why, but it does.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's fine now - just trying to offer up something that may make others happy.